# Method isn't pulling the correct variable from an Array

Tags: java, android, arrays, methods

This is supposed to be a dice app and each dice is supposed to alternate between 3 colors so each face value can be blue, yellow, or red, and so far I only am making the 1st dice colored. Now I have an array storing all the images to use for each color and theres 18 values in the array seeing as there's 6 sides of the dice and 3 colors for each sides. so I have my method taking 0-2 in the array which should be all just 1 in red blue and yellow, and then 2-5 should be 2 in red blue yellow. problem is whenever I run it, the total it shows is never the correct toal as the face value is always off. for example it will show a red 3 and a normal black and white 1 and the total will be 8. Any help would be greatly appreciated!

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {

int[] images = new int[] {

        // dicex1
        R.drawable.dicex1red,
        R.drawable.dicex1blue,
        R.drawable.dicex1yellow,

        // dicex2
        R.drawable.dicex2red,
        R.drawable.dicex2blue,
        R.drawable.dicex2yellow,

        // dicex3
        R.drawable.dicex3red,
        R.drawable.dicex3blue,
        R.drawable.dicex3yellow,

        // dicex4
        R.drawable.dicex4red,
        R.drawable.dicex4blue,
        R.drawable.dicex4yellow,

        // dicex5
        R.drawable.dicex5red,
        R.drawable.dicex5blue,
        R.drawable.dicex5yellow,

        // dicex6
        R.drawable.dicex6red, 
        R.drawable.dicex6blue,
        R.drawable.dicex6yellow, };

Random three = new Random();

MediaPlayer mp;
ImageView dice1, dice2;
TextView total;
Button roll;
int di1, di2, num;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    roll = (Button) findViewById(R.id.bRoll);
    total = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.tvTotal);
    dice1 = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.IVdice1);
    dice2 = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.IVdice2);
    mp = new MediaPlayer();
    final Random random = new Random();

    roll.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            mp.release();
            di1 = random.nextInt(6);
            di1++;
            di2 = random.nextInt(6);
            di2++;

            if (di1 == 1) {
                numb(2);

                numColor();
            } else if (di1 == 2) {
                numb(5); 
                num = num + 3;
                numColor();
            } else if (di1 == 3) {
                numb(8); 
                num = num + 6;
                numColor();
            } else if (di1 == 4) {
                numb(11); 
                num = num + 9;
                numColor();
            } else if (di1 == 5) {
                numb(14); 
                num = num + 12;
                numColor();
            } else if (di1 == 6) {
                numb(17); 
                num = num + 15 ;
                numColor();
            }

            if (di2 == 1) {
                dice2.setImageResource(R.drawable.dicex1);
            } else if (di2 == 2) {
                dice2.setImageResource(R.drawable.dicex2);
            } else if (di2 == 3) {
                dice2.setImageResource(R.drawable.dicex3);
            } else if (di2 == 4) {
                dice2.setImageResource(R.drawable.dicex4);
            } else if (di2 == 5) {
                dice2.setImageResource(R.drawable.dicex5);
            } else if (di2 == 6) {
                dice2.setImageResource(R.drawable.dicex6);
            }
            int answer = di1 + di2;
            total.setText("The total is " + answer);

            mp = MediaPlayer.create(getApplicationContext(),
R.raw.dice);
            mp.start();

        }

    });

}

@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
    return true;
}

public void numColor() {



    if (num == 1) {
        dice1.setImageResource(images[0]);
    } else if (num == 2) {
        dice1.setImageResource(images[1]);
    } else if (num == 3) {
        dice1.setImageResource(images[2]);
    } else if (num == 4) {
        dice1.setImageResource(images[3]);
    } else if (num == 6) {
        dice1.setImageResource(images[4]);
    } else if (num == 7) {
        dice1.setImageResource(images[5]);
    } else if (num == 8) {
        dice1.setImageResource(images[6]);
    } else if (num == 9) {
        dice1.setImageResource(images[7]);
    } else if (num == 10) {
        dice1.setImageResource(images[8]);
    } else if (num == 11) {
        dice1.setImageResource(images[11]);
    } else if (num == 12) {
        dice1.setImageResource(images[12]);
    } else if (num == 13) {
        dice1.setImageResource(images[13]);
    } else if (num == 14) {
        dice1.setImageResource(images[14]);
    } else if (num == 15) {
        dice1.setImageResource(images[15]);
    } else if (num == 16) {
        dice1.setImageResource(images[16]);
    } else if (num == 17) {
        dice1.setImageResource(images[17]);
    } else if (num == 18) {
        dice1.setImageResource(images[18]);
    } 
}

public void numb(int x){
    num = three.nextInt(x);
}
}
```

Comment: I'm having a hard time understanding. Correct me if I'm wrong. You want to figure out the proper drawable given color and value. Is that it?

Comment: Yeah, I want it to always randomly select 1 of the 3 colors for the number on the dice, but it won't select the correct drawable or something from the array because the total of the 2 dice never comes up correct.

Answer (score 0):

Here's what i would do

```
private static final int RED = 0;
private static final int BLUE = 1;
private static final int YELLOW = 2;

private int getResourceForDie(int color, int value) {
    return images[3*(value - 1) + color];
}
```

so to get the resource for a yellow die of value 3, you would call `getResourceForDie(YELLOW, 3)` where value is between 1 and 6 inclusive.

Comment: This looks like it could work but I'm pretty new to android and am kinda confused on how I would implement this in my app.

Comment: if you want dice1 to be a yellow die with value 3, you call `dice1.setImageResource(getResourceForDie(YELLOW, 3));`

Comment: Alright so I keep my array storing all the images, and then just add this method. How would I go about using a Random() to call a random number and color from this method?